# Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have the following component, that does not compile:

```
export default function MobileNav({routes, currentRouteIndex, handlePressedRoutedIndex}: MobileNavProp) {

   ...

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            ...
            ...
                    {
                        routes.map((rt, index) => (
                            <ListItem
                                divider
                                key={index}
                                button
                                component={Link}
                                to={rt.path}
                                selected={index === currentRouteIndex}
                                onClick={handleOnClickItem(index)}
                            >
                                <ListItemText primary={rt.name}/>
                            </ListItem>
                        ))
                    }
                </List>

            </SwipeableDrawer>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

The **routes** is defined as follows:

```
const routes: RoutesTable = [
      {name: "HOME", path: "/"},
      {name: "HOW IT WORKS", path: "/howitworks"},
      {name: "ABOUT US", path: "/aboutus"}
  ]
```

The compiler complains:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element; divider: true; key: number; button: true; component: <S = unknown>(props: LinkProps<S> & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>) => ReactElement<...> | null; to: string; selected: boolean; onClick: (event: MouseEvent<...>) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { button: true; } & { alignItems?: "center" | "flex-start" | undefined; autoFocus?: boolean | undefined; button?: boolean | undefined; ... 7 more ...; selected?: boolean | undefined; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'.
      Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { button: true; } & { alignItems?: "center" | "flex-start" | undefined; autoFocus?: boolean | undefined; button?: boolean | undefined; ... 7 more ...; selected?: boolean | undefined; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'.  TS2769

    87 |                                 key={index}
    88 |                                 button
  > 89 |                                 component={Link}
       |                                 ^
    90 |                                 to={rt.path}
    91 |                                 selected={index === currentRouteIndex}
    92 |                                 onClick={handleOnClickItem(index)}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `<ListItem>` is from https://material-ui.com/api/list-item/.

Comment: According to Material-UI docs, `ListItem` doesn't have any prop named `to`. Removing `to={rt.path}` seems to remove the compile error.

Comment: But I have passed `component={Link}`.

Comment: Have you check this https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/17645 ?

Comment: This is more appropriate https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/23622. However I do not get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using styled-components and I got the same error.

I solve this using an interface on my styled-component:

```
interface IStyledListItemButton {
  component: ElementType
  href: string // or to
}

export const StyledListItemButton = styled(
  ListItemButton
)<IStyledListItemButton>(({ theme }) => ({
  ... styles
}))
```

Now I don't get any errors using it on my component

```
<IStyledListItemButton
  component={Link}
  href="/home" // or to
/>
```